# Next Augustus in Future with Carbon

Tags: php-carbon

Is there  prettier way to get the full-date of the next 1st of August:

```
$year = date('Y') + 1;
if (date('j') >= 1 && date('j') <= 8) {
    $year = date('Y');
}
$nextAugust = '01-08-' . $year;
$nextAugust = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $nextAugust);
```

Preferably with Carbon PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code find next august with carbon object.

```
$nextAugust = Carbon::parse('first day of August' . (date('n') > 8 ? ' next year' : ''));
```

I hope my answer can help for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$nextAugust = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-08-' . (date('Y') + intval(date('m') / 8)));
```

**Clarification:**

Instead of the `if` condition, you can divide the current month by `8` and convert the resulting value to an integer using `intval(date('m') / 8)`. This will give you either `0` or `1`, and will be added to the current year. For example, if you are in March (i.e., `m` is `3`), you get `3/8` = `0`. Hence, next August will be in the same year because `2018 + 0` will be `2018`. On the other hand, if you are in October (i.e., `m` is `10`), you get `10/8` = `1`. Hence, next August will be in the next year because `2018 + 1` will be `2019`. Here's how you simply implement it:

Hope it helps.

Comment: What does the intval(date('m') / 8) do? I meant more like: ```Carbon::parse('next August')```, but that doesn't work..

Answer (score -2):

For me, I'll do:

```
$date = '01-08-';
$year_now = Carbon::now()->format('Y');
$date = $date.$year_now;
$carbon_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $date);
```

Let me know if it is not working.

Comment: Can't take this seriously

Comment: Are you trolling?